# Gradle Build Fails Due to "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Crunching Cruncher photo.png failed"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, drawable

I have just recently gotten into android app development.

When I try to run my app on a virtual machine the gradle build fails with the message: "**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.> Crunching Cruncher citruslogocolor.png failed, see logs**"

(citruslogocolor.png is an image file I use on the homepage)

Along with this all instances of R have now become errors in my java file for the activity.

I have cleaned gradle and rebuilt multiple times and I still have the same error. The image is also a png and I did not need to change the file type to put it in drawable.

Here is the XML code for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.citrusdynamics.citrus.MainActivity"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="sign up"
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_below="@id/signintext"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Sign up for a free Citrus™ user account"
        android:id="@+id/signuptext"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/citruslogo" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="sign in"
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/citruslogo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textColor="#000000" />




    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Existing users may sign in"
        android:id="@+id/signintext"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@id/signin"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/citruslogo"
        android:src="@drawable/citruslogocolor"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="Logo of Citrus Dynamics" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Java for that Activity. Now with errors on every instance of 'R':

```
package net.citrusdynamics.citrus;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);
    Button signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    signup.setOnClickListener(viewhandler1);


}

View.OnClickListener viewhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        Intent signup_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(signup_intent);
    }
};
}
```

I need this app to work in my android vm so any help is much apprecited, thank you.

Comment: @Ozel Would you please add the log?

Comment: @SkyWalker Sorry I'm new to android studio. Where are those located

Comment: In console where you get error `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.> Crunching Cruncher citruslogocolor.png failed, see logs"`. Provide the full portion.

Comment: @SkyWalker I just solved my problem, I'm really sorry for wasting your time. I ran the png through a png converter and it ended up working

Comment: Thats great. Carry on. We are always keep in touch.

Comment: @DemirhanOzel You should answer the question yourself and then accept the answer, so this question is marked as resolved.

Comment: @F43nd1r will do thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.
I ran the png through a png converter and it ended up working.
Even though the image was actually a png.
It's confusing but it worked.